# Getting list of users in a group

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know I can use `net localgroup Administrators` to get a list of all users in that group, but how can I iterate through the users outputted by that command?

Using this code gives me fluff (i.e. The command completed successfully, etc.)

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%b IN ('net localgroup Administrators') do (
     echo %%b
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('net localgroup Administrators^|more +6^|find /v "The command completed successfully."') do echo %%b
```

You may have to adjust the number after `more` to better suit your needs. Basically, this takes the output of `net localgroup Administrators`,

Comment: Do you know of any cases where I might have to adjust the more number?

Comment: Only if the header of `net localgroup Administrators` somehow takes up more (or less) than six lines. I was really just concerned about word wrap maybe messing things up, but if the code above works for you then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Here's a version that doesn't use `more` and `find`: `FOR /f "skip=6 delims=" %%u IN ('net localgroup Administrators') DO (IF "%%u" NEQ "The command completed successfully." echo %%u)`